# Removing Support Library Version 7

Tags: android, android-support-library

I've recently downloaded Support Library from SDK, whenever I want to make new project, Appcompat file shows off.

I tried to remove the Support Library and did many tries to use normal Activity instead of ActionBarActivity, but the same problem happens whenever I want to make new project.

How to do it without re-installing ADT(I don't want to re-install it again).

Comment: Are you selecting options that need appcompat in order to work? (eg. minSdkTarget, fragments etc)

Comment: Minimum sdk api 8, max api 19, no fragments. I'm just creating normal activity and the settings seem to use support library v7

Comment: The following error shows even if I chose empty activity:
res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio?

Comment: I've successfully get over this problem by choosing None Theme while creating new project. The problem is when you update ADT, support library v7 will add itself.
Btw I'm using Eclipse, thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: These automatically generated in order to help development. For having a common theme and ActionBar in API 8 you need to use AppCompat.